# How to make SELECT from RDS cluster or How to configure data pipeline with RDS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I have 1 RDS this is Cluser (Serverless)
How to connect to the RDS Cluster and make "Select * from.." using boto3?

**Why I asked**:
I tried to configure data pipeline to save data from DB Cluster to S3 bucket, but I have to use only DB Instances. And if I can't create DB instances I thinking about lambda function which will be connect to DB cluster (through boto3) and try to save data to s3..

I know how to did it if I have RDS Instances, but I have RDS Cluster and I can't (don't allow) to create instance.

BTW: I will be happy any comment which can help me with boto3 or data pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

boto3 is used to make API calls to AWS, such as creating and deleting the Amazon RDS cluster. It is *not* used to connect to the database itself.

An Amazon RDS database is a normal installation of the chosen database. You should programmatically connect to the database using a SQL client. For example, if RDS is using MySQL, then use the Python `mysql.connector` library to connect to the database. There is **no need to use boto3 to connect to the database**.